# Create office "news" displayboard?

Tags: javascript, html

Looking to have a list of say 5-10 websites which are all news based and often update with very interesting news articles every 15-20 minutes.

I want to create a small script which can have a pool of 3 websites which will automatically refresh every 30 seconds and basically 'rotate through' the list of sites. My only issue is I want to strip down the website so it hides the 'header' and 'menu' HTML when the page renders and that way you are left only with the breaking news article.

Also, would like to include facebook pages (but only the most recent post, so hide the header banner image, etc.

Is this possible?

I've tried this but it blocks the websites I want... (does not support frames)... also, how would I strip code (headers, etc.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
html,body,iframe{height:100%;width:100%;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
html,body{overflow:hidden;}
</style>
<iframe></iframe>
<script>
var timer = 5;
var sites = [
    'http://www.bing.com/',
    'http://www.ask.com/',
    'https://duckduckgo.com/'
];
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
var index = 0;
var cycle = function() {
    frame.src = sites[index];
    if(++index>=sites.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(cycle,timer*1000);
}
cycle();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.